# How to save and open connect the SQLite database file in another location but the application temporary folder in windows 8 RT?

Tags: windows-8, sqlite, microsoft-metro

guys, now I have an issue, it really makes me wonder.

I'm currently developing a Windows 8 RT app, the app store data to local, so I choice to use the SQLite for WinRT(include the SQLite.cs SQLiteAsync.cs, SQLite3.dll) , the SQLite for WinRT store the database file in the application temporary folder by default

```
public SQLiteConnection (string databasePath, bool storeDateTimeAsTicks = false): this (databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create, storeDateTimeAsTicks)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new SQLiteConnection and opens a SQLite database specified by databasePath.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="databasePath">
        /// Specifies the path to the database file.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="storeDateTimeAsTicks">
        /// Specifies whether to store DateTime properties as ticks (true) or strings (false). You
        /// absolutely do want to store them as Ticks in all new projects. The default of false is
        /// only here for backwards compatibility. There is a *significant* speed advantage, with no
        /// down sides, when setting storeDateTimeAsTicks = true.
        /// </param>
        public SQLiteConnection (string databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, bool storeDateTimeAsTicks = false)
        {
            DatabasePath = databasePath;

#if NETFX_CORE
            SQLite3.SetDirectory(/*temp directory type*/2, Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path);
#endif

            Sqlite3DatabaseHandle handle;

#if SILVERLIGHT || USE_CSHARP_SQLITE
            var r = SQLite3.Open (databasePath, out handle, (int)openFlags, IntPtr.Zero);
#else
            // open using the byte[]
            // in the case where the path may include Unicode
            // force open to using UTF-8 using sqlite3_open_v2
            var databasePathAsBytes = GetNullTerminatedUtf8 (DatabasePath);
            var r = SQLite3.Open (databasePathAsBytes, out handle, (int) openFlags, IntPtr.Zero);
#endif

            Handle = handle;
            if (r != SQLite3.Result.OK) {
                throw SQLiteException.New (r, String.Format ("Could not open database file: {0} ({1})", DatabasePath, r));
            }
            _open = true;

            StoreDateTimeAsTicks = storeDateTimeAsTicks;

            BusyTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds (0.1);
        }
```

assign to the app temporary folder path.

Now I want to save the database file to another folder, like document folder, in order to save the user data and behavior, import the data when user re-install the app. So I change the save folder, the code as follow

```
StorageFolder sourceFolder = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFolderAsync(FolderName);
DatabasePath = Path.Combine(sourceFolder.Path, DBName);

SQLite3.SetDirectory(/*temp directory type*/2, storeFloderPath);
```

but it throw an excetion at:

```
var r = SQLite3.Open(databasePathAsBytes, out handle, (int)openFlags, IntPtr.Zero);

            Handle = handle;
            if (r != SQLite3.Result.OK)
            {
                throw SQLiteException.New(r, String.Format("Could not open database file: {0} ({1})", DatabasePath, r));
            }
```

it says cannot open the file. I think maybe the problem is 'SQLite3.SetDirectory(/*temp directory type*/2, storeFloderPath)', the '2' is the stand temp directory type. These no official document, so I try the argument from 0 to 6, it did't work as well, the exception as same as original.

Anyone know how to do it, or it has some error in my codes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you specify that you access the documents folder in the app manifest?

Comment: if you do go this route, specifically with the DocumentsLibrary, know that you'll need a "company" account to deploy such an app to the store, not just an individual developer one.

Comment: @sLedgem, yes, of course I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all you answers, I found a sick way to solve it, When I want to open the database connection in other folder, firstly copy the database file to the application local folder(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder), and then connect to the database file, and then it successed.

But I wish the developer of the SQLite for WinRT could remark the problem, and fix it